# Formatting lists for ebook format?

Tags: formatting, ebook

For lists such as:

```
Topic 1
xxx
xxxxx xxx
xxx
xxx xxx
xxxx

Topic 2
xxx
xxxxx xxx
xxx
xxx xxx
xxxx
```

is there some different way to represent them since they won't format well in mobi and epub?

These list will break over onto another page.  Since list items are numbers and just a hand full of words, breaking over into another page won't look too good.

I need some other representation that gets the content out of a list so it will flow nicely in the very fluid formats of mobi and epub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple ways you can try to handle this. The bottom line, though, is that ebooks are reflowable content, unlike a print book or a PDF for instance, so you only have so much control over how the content actually appears.

Take a look at the [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebi.asp), which describes the `page-break-inside` CSS property. If you set this to `avoid` for your list, it instructs the reader that it should *try not* to break this element across multiple pages, or in other words, it will try to keep it all on one page. The downside of course is that you may end up with a large vertical whitespace before the content if the reader decides it needs to move the entire thing onto the next page in order to fit it.

This can also potentially cause problems if your content really is too big for a page (which, remember, you don't know the size of for an ebook). Depending on the reader, it might break the content onto multiple pages if it has to (ideally it will do this), or it might truncate whatever content doesn't fit (which would suck).

You might also look at the `page-break-before` and `page-break-after` which can help make things look better if they are moved entirely onto a different page.

Another option is to try to reformat your list. For instance, I had a long list which I replaced with a table [here](http://sparrowpub.com/html-book/chapter0030.xhtml) in order to make it a "double-wide" list, so that it would only require about half as much vertical space, and more easily fit onto one page. In another instance ([here](http://sparrowpub.com/html-book/chapter0018.xhtml)), I turned the list sideways (also with a table) so that it would fit better.

Comment: Do tables always stay together?  By the way, which app are you using?  I'm currently using Scrivener and haven't tried any CSS editing with it yet.

Comment: No, definitely not. Tables will be reflowed just like anything else. You can apply `page-break-inside` to tables as well, but with all the same caveats. The reason for using tables would be to "fold" your list in half, and put elements side by side. That way it takes up twice as much horizontal space, but half as much vertical space (roughly). I created my own program called Tome, which I use for writing: https://bitbucket.org/bmearns/tome. I write using a simple markup and then generate various output formats from that. Then I manually edit the HTML and CSS for EPUB and Mobi.

Comment: Amazon now has KF8.  I'm not sure that even uses mobi.  It seems too.  But when coding your own HTML/CSS, how do you keep up with all the format changes?

Comment: You probably have some good input for this question http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/8099/how-do-you-keep-up-with-all-the-ebook-formats.

Comment: Amazon currently still accepts Mobi format, I think they convert it to KF8 after upload. No idea if they will continue to going forward or not. EPUB is an open and standard and widely supported; this is what `tome` actually generates. You can find a program called kindlegen from Amazon that converts from EPUB to Mobi. I'm not sure what you mean by format changes: like different file formats? I wrote tome to generate EPUB, and use kindlegen to convert to Mobi. If these stop being widely supported, I'll just have to update `tome` or use a new tool. But I think EPUB will be around for a while.

Comment: In regards to epub and Amazon converting them to mobi, should you expect the epub formatting to change once it is output to mobi?  If that is the case, why not just generate a mobi from say Scrivener?

Comment: Yes, you should assume that the formatting and layout *may* change slightly converting from EPUB to Mobi (or vice versa). From what I recall of Mobi, they both use HTML and CSS, but I believe there are slight variations on what they support, so they are not 100% inter-convertible. I get the impression that you really want to use Scrivener: is there something holding you back from that? Whatever tool you use, if it natively supports outputting to your desired format, you should do that rather than output to one format and then try to convert it.

Comment: Editor is using Word.  There's not a clean way to bounce between Word and Scrivener.  Scrivener will output a cleaner epub than Word.

Comment: Ah, well if your editor is using an incompatible tool, I suppose your only optiona would be to a) convince them to use a compatible tool, b) give in and use the tool they're using, or c) deal with using different tools. If you really want to use Scrivener and you can't convince your editor to, maybe you can convince them to use Word's change tracking feature. It will definitely be more work for you, but the idea is that when they make edits, you can easily see the changes they made, and then make the same changes to your document in Scrivener.